# Conditional sentences in business writing

Tags: conditionals

I found this question strange.

> Complete the sentence with a correct word:
>   *When you contracted with us to find the right candidates for that position, we .... to send you a list of potential candidates for review.*
>   Here is the list of words to fill out:
>   *- will promise
>
>   - promise
>
>   - have promised
>
>   - promised*

All 3 types of conditional statement I've learnt so far, would offer the correct word as **would promise**. But I don't see that option here.

Could you explain this question for me?

Comment: It's not a conditional sentence.

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Shor says, this is not a conditional sentence. It is true that a *when* clause may express a condition, like an *if* clause, but only if it is cast in the present tense **and** in the indicative mood; it cannot be employed to express a condition with a past form, even if that form expresses present counterfactuality. This *when* clause employs the past form, *contract**ed***; consequently, the *when* clause does not express a condition but a temporal reference point. It may be paraphrased

> At the time you contracted with us ...

That clearly establishes the *Reference Time* of the sentence as past, so the main clause must employ a past-tensed verb construction. *Promise*, *will promise* and *have promised* are all present-tensed constructions, but *promised* is past-tensed. *Promised* has to be the answer.

Comment: I think the "standard" word in such contexts would more likely be ***undertook***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ? But it's not on the list.

Comment: Can't help that. I think such multiple choice questions are a bit silly, anyway. Personally, I'd vote for anyone who changed their name by deed poll to [**none of the above**](https://www.facebook.com/nota.noneoftheabove)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah: teach English or teach EnglishTestTaking? Huge  debate over here since No Child Left Behind. I gather it's sort of a sensitive issue over there, too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Writing advice is OT. :)

Comment: @Kris **Asking** for writing is advice is OT. I find no such constraint in the page-formerly-known-as-FAQ on Answers or Comments.

Comment: I think "multiple choice" questions are usually presented that way to help the *teachers/markers*, not the students. But even in a more "exacting" discipline like mathematics they can be somewhat limiting. *Q: What's the square root of 4? A: 1, 2, 3* - what about the potentially *exceptional* student who wanted to answer ***-2**?* In this specific case, OP's ***would promise*** is a little awkward to justify (but *possible*, I think). And it would certainly be quite reasonable to use ***would have promised***, in contexts that aren't particularly "contrived". But it's really an ELL question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Really? It seems to me that "When you did this we would have promised to do that" is only possible if a further condition is specified.

Comment: that does seem to be the most common context, but there's nothing wrong with [*The bus was due any minute, and when it came, I would have to say good-by to my best friends.*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4YupB8xcRwwC&pg=PA57&dq=%22when+it+came+i+would+have%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4hG7UqTFHs3whQfF8YDgBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22when%20it%20came%20i%20would%20have%22&f=false)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's  a different *have*: *have to* = *can* rather than *have* + pappl = perfect.

Comment: ["When we arrived, it would have been easy for them simply to let us fend for ourselves."](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22When+we+arrived%2C+it+would+have+been+easy+for+them+simply+to+let+us+fend+for+ourselves.%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)